# Kubuntu 20.04 Keyboard Alt+1

Tags: keyboard, kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, keyboard-layout

In KDE plasma .
I use Alt+1 for switch to tab[1] in firefox or konsole .

when i add persian keyboard layout (without switch to that) .  this shortcut (alt+1) not working .
i test this problem on other layouts like arabic , china , russia, ... .
only persian layout has this problem .

**NOTE : this happens when I only add persian layout without switch to that .**

Comment: Is the issue with both ALT key left and right or just one of them? Which variant of Persian keyboard exactly? It is possible that ALT is used as 3rd level shift for that layout.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue and solved it by assigning a system custom shortcut (to any program/url, can be `konsole` or `vim`) under Settings > Workspace > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts to alt+1 and then deleting it.